# jqGrid, jQuery UI - Resize grid on hiding a pane

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

What I want to do is: when the user clicks to hide a pane (red circles on pic 1)...

[image]

...I want that my grid resizes according to the window size. In this example, I wanted my grid to fill all the space and not how it is shown on pic 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup your grid with `width: null` and `shrinkToFit: false` properties, in this way the grid will automatically adapt itself to the space.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jAy2g/